# Can I make a mesh object transparent to sun light in Blender yet stay opaque in the viewport, using Cycles render engine?

Tags: visibility

I'm building a landscape with a visible moon. The moon should shine its light over the landscape. The moon is a  round transparent plane containing a moon image + a light emitting object behind it to make this image visible. I still need a powerful light source to illuminate the whole landscape and draw dramatic shadows.The light should come from the direction of the moon. To me it seems that point, spot and area lights are no choice. They would be visible bright spots. Now I've tried sun light. The problem is that When that light is set up to come from the direction of the moon, the moon is throwing a shadow on the camera and on the light path of the atmospheric fog (the dark 'halo' around the moon in the image). So ideally, the moon should be completely transparent to the sun light, still being visible when rendering. Is there a way?[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all: why do you put a light emitting object behind the moon to make the image visible? Just use an *Emission* shader for the moon and plug the image texture into the *Color*. And if you don't want it to cast a shadow on the environment or like in this example on a ground plane, go to the *Object Properties* > *Visibility* > *Ray Visibility* and disable *Shadow*:

[image: moon]

Comment: Thank you Gordon, your advice did the trick.

Comment: @jacerman You're welcome. If this solved your problem please consider accepting this answer, read more about it here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)